# What linguistic sources discuss doubled -ed in -edly and -edness words?

Tags: english, morphology, affixes

Some linguists have written analyses of "double *-er* suffixation" in English, in formations from particle verbs such as *fix up* > *fixer upper.* For example: ["Double -er suffixation in English: morphological, phonological and sociolinguistic reflections", by Jim Walker](https://journals.openedition.org/lexis/867)

Another type of derivative from particle verbs that seems similar to me is what could be termed "double *-ed*" constructions, where *-ed-...-edly* and *-ed-*...*-edness* appear: e.g. "messeduppedness" and "[fuckeduppedly](https://books.google.com/books?id=Nhe2yvx6hP8C&pg=PT582&lpg=PT582&dq=%22fuckeduppedly%22&source=bl&ots=K5Jy_eZ0sg&sig=ACfU3U36Z4thkXjwdf0uUEAoKGYh0_xllg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ3LWDr7X2AhURM30KHVokBeQQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22fuckeduppedly%22&f=false)" (the latter attested in *Infinite Jest* by David Foster Wallace).

Does anyone know of linguistic analyses of these *-edness* and *-edly* forms?

Comment: I won't call it doubled -ed, it is just a euphonic t inserted in the consonant clusters -pn- and -pl- and than written as ed.

Comment: It certainly doesn't strike me as (purely) euphonic in nature but rather as some sort of morphological doubling just as brass tacks suggests (for one thing, there's nothing wrong with the clusters -pn- or -pl- in this context, cf. e.g. _sharpness_, _deepness_, _cheapness_, _sharply_, _deeply_, _cheaply_).

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica It is absolutely not a euphonic stop to split up the cluster. For one thing, it adds a syllable – optionally in _messed-uppedness_ but, at least in my speech, mandatorily in _fucked-uppedly_, which can only be /fʌkˈdʌpədlɨ/ to me (and similarly with _worn-outedly_, _done-innedly_, etc.). And as Miztli says, those clusters don’t develop excrescent stops elsewhere, only in passive participle constructions.